# Nonlinear Exponential Regression with Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js, exponential

I am trying to fit exponential data to an exponential regression with tensorflow.js, such as:

y(x) = c0*e^(k*x)

I have followed examples where they have fitted a linear regression with just a few epochs, like [here](https://medium.com/@tristansokol/basic-tutorial-with-tensorflow-js-linear-regression-aa68b16e5b8e).

The problem is that when I change the tensor equation to an exponential function, even if I increase to 500-5000 epochs and providing close initial values, it does not fit properly. With a large learning rate, the variables go to very high values, and low learning rate the variables don't substantially change.

Is there anything I am doing wrong in the code? Is it because optimization is not fit for exponential functions? Is there any other way to do implement this in a browser without using tf.js?

The code I have used is:

```
const x = tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]);
const y = tf.tensor1d([2.5879,3.1153,3.7041,4.6216,5.2307,5.6205,6.9904,7.8416,9.0201,10.5586,12.1638,14.1438,16.5961,19.2497,22.3430]);


const c0 = tf.scalar(2).variable();
const k = tf.scalar(0.10).variable();

// y = c0*e^(k*x)
const fun = (x) => x.mul(k).exp().mul(c0);
const cost = (pred, label) => pred.sub(label).square().mean();

const learning_rate = 0.001;
const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(learning_rate);

// Train the model.
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    optimizer.minimize(() => cost(fun(x), y));
}

console.log(`c0: ${c0.dataSync()}, k: ${k.dataSync()}`);

const preds = fun(x).dataSync();
preds.forEach((pred, i) => {
   console.log(`x: ${i}, pred: ${pred}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the optimizer used and the set of initial value that might not be converging. It they are not set correctly the model can diverge.

```js
const x = tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]);
const y = tf.tensor1d([2.5879,3.1153,3.7041,4.6216,5.2307,5.6205,6.9904,7.8416,9.0201,10.5586,12.1638,14.1438,16.5961,19.2497,22.3430]);


const c0 = tf.scalar(2).variable();
const k = tf.scalar(0.10).variable();

// y = c0*e^(k*x)
const fun = (x) => x.mul(k).exp().mul(c0);
const cost = (pred, label) => pred.sub(label).square().mean();

const learning_rate = 0.1;
const optimizer = tf.train.adagrad(learning_rate);

// Train the model.
for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    optimizer.minimize(() => cost(fun(x), y));
}

console.log(`c0: ${c0.dataSync()}, k: ${k.dataSync()}`);
fun(x).print()

// [2.4752154, 2.899802, 3.3972201, 3.9799631, 4.6626663, 5.4624777, 6.3994851, 7.4972224, 8.7832594, 10.289897, 12.0549774, 14.1228304, 16.545393, 19.3835087, 22.7084637]
```

Using `tf.train.adagrad`, it seems that we have a good convergence. For the initializing value, we can also use `Math.Random()` just for random value and run the similation many times until we find the set of values that lead to a better prediction. Likewise the `learning_rate` and the number of `epochs` used can be fine tuned

Additionnally, it is possibly to use several optimizers and see which one performs best in overall

Comment: Thank you so much! It is the change of optimiser what made a huge difference when using it for the larger arrays that I am using in the implementation. For the initial values I use the parameters obtained with linear least squares after linearizing the data and equation. Thanks again, I will accept this answer.